# Upsell and related product hide when recently active product display

Tags: magento-1.14

I have a strange problem in magento Enterprise 1.14.1 ,there are three block in product page,upsell,related and recently viewed product.When open Product page first time, then display two blocks
upsell and related product and when click and open a product in another tab for display recent viewed product and refresh page first one then two block (upsell and related product) hide and recent viewed product display.When refresh cache again displays all blocks(upsell,related and recent viewed product)
Can anybody tell me please what's problem here?